# Switch statements gets ignored after my if-else statements

Tags: java, arrays

```
//Scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Variables
        double bmi;                        // Body Mass Index
        double weight;                     // Weight in kilograms
        double height;                     // Height in meters
        String[] classification = {"Underweight", "Normal", "Overweight", "Obese"};

        System.out.print("Your weight in KG \n");
        weight = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter height in meters: \n");
        height = scan.nextDouble();
        bmi = weight / (height * height);

        if (bmi < 18.5) {
            System.out.print("You're " + classification[0] + "\n");
        } else if (bmi < 25) {
            System.out.print("You're " + classification[1] + "\n");
        } else if (bmi < 30) {
            System.out.print("You're " + classification[2] + "\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print("You're " + classification[3] + "\n");
        }

        switch (Arrays.toString(classification)) {
            case "Underweight":
                System.out.println("Underweight");
                break;
            case "Normal":
                System.out.println("Normal");
                break;
            case "Overweight":
                System.out.println("A bit overweighted");
                break;
            case "Obese":
                System.out.println("A bit obese");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ok");
                break;
        }
    }
```

output,, my switch statement does not work after the if-else statements. It ignores everything and jumps directly to the default in my switch. While my intentions are to follow up with some text after the if-else. So basically if my calculations show me i'm overweighted than my switch statement must now to jump to case "overweighted" and print out that piece of code.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Arrays.toString(classification)` will always have `[]` in it.

Comment: `Arrays.toString(classification)` will print `[Underweight, Normal, Overweight, Obese]` and will never match any of your cases

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! Placing an [] will give me the next error 'class.' expected

Comment: There is no point in switching over the result of `Arrays.toString(classification)`. It's (effectively) a constant, so it would do the same thing each time.

Comment: I so not see, how a single case ist selected in the Switch case. You need a specific classification for a single BMI. For example create a variable which is filled in the If Else and is Used in the Switch case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `Arrays.toString(classification)` which is [Underweight, Normal, Overweight, Obese] does not match any switch case.

The solution could be something like this:

```
String result = null;
if (bmi < 18.5) {
        System.out.print("You're " + classification[0] + "\n");
        result = classification[0];
    } else if (bmi < 25) {
        System.out.print("You're " + classification[1] + "\n");
        result = classification[1];
    } else if (bmi < 30) {
        System.out.print("You're " + classification[2] + "\n");
        result = classification[2];
    } else {
        System.out.print("You're " + classification[3] + "\n");
        result = classification[3];
    }

    switch (result) {
        case "Underweight":
            System.out.println("Underweight");
            break;
        case "Normal":
            System.out.println("Normal");
            break;
        case "Overweight":
            System.out.println("A bit overweighted");
            break;
        case "Obese":
            System.out.println("A bit obese");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Ok");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You can also move the `System.out.print("You're " + classification[X] + "\n");` out of the `if`s and do a single `System.out.print("You're " + result + "\n");` afterwards.

Comment: I'm getting an error if I add an String result. It says that my String result is not initialized yet.

Comment: String result = Null; will make my if - else output to null and thus also not respond to my switch.

Comment: @Jaws edit code to something like this: `String result = null;` or `String result = "";`

Comment: I tried editing my code to String result = null; of String result = ""; My output is then into " " open space and does not output anything?

Comment: @Jaws  you should not delete the code above if statement

Comment: Thanks @mohsenJsh that solved my problem! I overlooked result = classification[0]. Thanks again!